# Batch Processing to use multiple pods

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core, react, kubernetes

We have a frontend application in React and a backend application in .NET Core which were deployed in a single Kubernetes cluster of 3 pods (it can autoscale). Before the application, we have a load balancer and an API gateway.

We have a page which lists the clinicians and, on clicking, a process runs to create the payroll. Payroll is processed for each clinician. On a successful run of one clinician payroll, it calls the payroll process for the next clinician.

It always uses a single pod and it is taking a long time to process.

We have thought of using the following methods to utilize all of the pods:

1. Publish event to Kafka and consume message to process payroll
2. On Payroll Create, insert basic details into a mysql table and write a background service to process the payroll

Are there any efficient methods to handle batch processing to utilize all the pods?

Comment: you shouldnt link your website to this offline task, have the website add a row to your db/kafka and have a completely different program poll and do the payroll. you can then split this task up among as many pods as you like